# Is function `number of TM which terminates on an empty word` computable?

Tags: turing-machines, computability, reductions, undecidability

> Let f: N → N be a function where `f(n) = number of Turing Machines over input alphabet {0, 1}, states: {0, 1, ..., n} and work alphabet {_ (blank), 0, 1, ... n} which terminates on a empty word`.
>
> Is `f` computable?

Let's call a TM which solves this problem `K`.

It feels like this problem is uncomputable. If we can't even determine if particular TM halts on an empty word ([Halting problem reducing to the blank tape halting problem](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/41239/halting-problem-reducing-to-the-blank-tape-halting-problem)), then intuitively finding number of TMs with this property should be even harder. But I can't think of any reduction since this problem doesn't utilize any particular TM in input, its input is just a number (in the question I linked above - BLANKHALT, TM takes a machine as an input so we can provide a specific machine - anything we want - for example machine from instance of the HALT problem, but this is not a case in this problem).

At first I wanted to reduce BLANKHALT problem: I wanted to measure its number of states, alphabet, run the `K` TM with number of states BLANKHALT instance has and while counting the number of TMs which terminated on empty word, check if this is BLANKHALT machine I have just asked for. **BUT** I cannot do this, since I cannot assume K even enumerates the TMs, right? If `K` existed, it might have a magical way to solve the question, without checking all possible TMs one-by-one, right?

Comment: You don't need to worry about how `K` might work. You need to think about what you could do if you had such a `K`.

Comment: That's why my idea to check if specific Turing Machine is contained in "terminates on empty word" set is invalid, right?

Answer (score 2):

*Is that proof correct?*

Let's assume `f` is computable. Then I can show a TM which solves halting problem, actually even more - a TM which prints all halting TMs of given size.

This TM works as following:

1. Using blackbox for `f`, calculate `f(n)`
2. Iterate through ALL possible TMs of input alphabet {0, 1}, states {0, 1..., n}, work alphabet {_, 0, 1, .... n}
3. Simulate each machine on empty input **BUT** we don't check TM machine one by one. We check TMs STEP BY STEP. That means for each TM we make its one step.
4. When TM terminates, add 1 to counter
5. When counter reaches f(n), then we know which machines terminates and which don't. We have solved halting problem. **Contradiction**

The key is we  don't simulate TM machines one by one, but step by step, thus we don't get looped and we always terminate.

Comment: Yes, this works. One minor concern that doesn't come up in this case but is worth mentioning is *how* we interleave the execution of the TMs. In this case, because there are only a finite number of relevant TMs, we can just iterate through them incrementing each in turn. When we're dealing with an infinite number of TMs, though, we use a technique called [dovetailing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dovetailing_(computer_science)) since if we just took a single step from each TM before taking the second step, we'd never get to the second step of any. Again, this isn't an issue in this case.